# Parent DIV not expanding to fit height of child div content

Tags: html, css, dom, web

I have a problem with my CSS where the height of the parent div (#cotentWrapper) is not expanding to fit the height of the child div (#bodyContent) once its content overflows. We are using percentages for our heights. We have tried various solutions found here on stack overflow but none resolved this problem. We have tried setting height to auto on #contentWrapper which solved our problem specified above it caused our nav bar to disappear which is also encapsulated in the #contentWrapper div. We have set min-heights on all DIVs it should work.

[image]

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>  </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link href="~/Content/AccountDetailsStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="contentWrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="logoWrapper">
                <div id="logoImg"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="contentBoxShadow">
            <div id="navigation">

            </div>

            <div id="bodyContent">
                @RenderBody()
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vidisse corrumpit mel ea, te purto oportere assueverit nam. Ut pro mazim utinam gloriatur, eum tempor eruditi eu, iudico laboramus nec ei. Ancillae offendit officiis vim ea. Cu fabellas sapientem maiestatis his, at consequat deseruisse sea. Illum singulis suavitate mea no, vivendum tincidunt eloquentiam ius an. His no etiam copiosae, quo an delicata volutpat petentium.

                An esse ridens ullamcorper ius, an est scaevola voluptatibus. Est ne iusto oratio. Laboramus deseruisse nec te, laoreet accumsan ut pri. Qui eu lorem repudiare, utroque epicuri ius ne. Ipsum adversarium definitionem eu vis, an vim paulo discere atomorum.

                Cu case bonorum vix, te sit habeo audiam electram. Ad cum graeco sadipscing, justo mandamus pertinacia mel id, ei eam soluta melius inimicus. Ad vel propriae aliquando, graeci aliquam petentium ea his. Mel ut maiorum albucius reprehendunt. Sed referrentur neglegentur te, usu ea quot aliquando, eu mei recusabo constituam vituperatoribus. Oratio volutpat tincidunt per et, at vitae facete virtute vis.

                Ut quis solum qui, essent utamur eloquentiam no sea. Est eros suscipit deseruisse ex. Sit illud tractatos consectetuer te. Ad mutat noluisse eum. At sit volumus tincidunt.

                Prompta alterum adolescens ei his. Ex inani quidam docendi nam, ea natum veritus vel, homero vulputate intellegat et duo. Tempor volumus mel id, ad probo viderer invenire mel. Civibus lucilius in per. An ignota nominavi praesent usu. Sed quando indoctum conclusionemque ad, vim amet petentium cu, summo eruditi ne vix. Habemus maluisset reprimique ad nam, vero laudem ad quo.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:
    *
    {
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
    }

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

body
{
    background-image: url("Images/textured_background.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#contentWrapper
{
    width: 88%;
    height: 100%;
    //height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#contentBoxShadow
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 85%;
    height: 85%;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    background-color: pink;
    position: relative;
}

#bodyContent
{
    width: 90%;
    height: 93%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 93%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header
{
    height: 15%;
    width: 100%;
}

#logoWrapper
{
    padding-top: 1.5%;
    padding-bottom: 1.5%;
    height: 97%;
    width: 100%;
}

#logoImg
{
    background-image:url("Images/logo.png");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

#contentBoxShadow:before {
    box-shadow: -15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 15px;
}

#contentBoxShadow:after {
    box-shadow: 15px 0 15px -15px inset;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    width: 15px;
    top: 0;
}

#navigation 
{
    height: 7%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #004A94 0%, #003366 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #004A94 0%, #003366 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #004A94 0%, #003366 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #004A94), color-stop(1, #003366));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #004A94 0%, #003366 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #004A94 0%, #003366 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is lacking a little bit of the HTML, but if I have correctly understood the question, removing the height and min-height on #contentBoxShadow the solves the problem.  You may have to remove the height from and min-height from #contentWrapper as well, but that part of the HTML is missing.

```
#contentBoxShadow
{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/32x50fdv/

Edit: also note that in your CSS you have tried to comment out a line using a double-forward-slash, which in CSS will not work.  You need to use /**/ instead:

```
//height: auto;
```

should be

```
/*height: auto;*/
```

Comment: I've tried your solution. This also removes the navbar as it and #bodyContent use percentages so that it fits the entire page. Removing height from #contentBoxShadow means the browser doesn't no how to calculate the height of both of these child elements e.g 93%% of what?

Comment: Can you post your full HTML?

Comment: Would it be OK to scroll the content in #bodyContent like this: http://jsfiddle.net/32x50fdv/1/?

Comment: Unfortunately I need the page to scroll not the div but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Let me know if I got this right: you have body and #contentWrapper that should be at least 100% of window height.  Then you have a #header that should be exactly 15% of the window height.  Then you have a #contentBoxShadow that should be at least 85% of the window height.  Inside that, you have #navigation that should be 7% of of the #contentBoxShadow, whether #contentBoxShadow is 85% of the the window height, or 2500% of the window height (the more content you have, the taller the #navigation will be?  Finally you have #bodyContent that should take of the remaining 93% of #contentBoxShadow

Comment: yes that is correct. I have set height auto on #contentBoxShadow which fixes the overflowing problem however with this solution I can no longer use percentages on the child elements which is an issue cause i am using percentages to ensure the webpage fits the screen